# How can we implement Calendar?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-directives

How can we implement Calendar in Angular2 using typescript? Do we have any directives to import?

Comment: PrimeNG has a calendar component for Angular2. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

Answer (score 0):

PrimeNG provides the Datepicker however there is no built-in component available for Calendar in Angular2 (like ui-calendar) as of now (to the best of my knowledge)